# What is the reason of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' in Python 3.8.10 and Requirement already satisfied in anaconda location problem?

Tags: python, windows, pip, mysql-connector, anaconda3

I need to import mysql-connector and I installed it by using `pip install mysql-connector-python`.
After the installation, I can see the same error is displayed.

[image: SourceCode]

[image: Error Image - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql']

After that again I tried to install mysql connector, but it displayed that *Requirement already satisfied* and show a path in anaconda lib folder.

[image: Already Exists]

Is there any effect from previous installation on Anaconda and how to import mysql-connector to code?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for that, I changed the interpreter of the code into **('base': conda)**. It worked correctly without any error.

[image: solution_change the interpreter]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solved with the command below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRDsJ.jpg)

**pip install mysql-connector**